# what exactly does a metapackage contain?

Tags: ros, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is it that the metapackage only contains CMakelists.txt and manifest file ( that includes the package group ) and nothing else ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253359/what-exactly-does-a-metapackage-contain-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [REP-140: Package Manifest Format Two Specification - export - metapackage](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#metapackage) should answer your questions.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-01-31**:
That worked ! Thanks